# Mesh moves to the incorrect location once parented

Tags: rigging

I'm working on a stylized model of Prototype Po for a project and each time I parent any finger segment to the rig, it moves away.[image: Before]

The way I rig is by simply selecting my meshes, the rig with the correct bone selected, control + p, and then clicking bone in object mode. Finally, please keep in mind I'm nowhere near a blender expert, so more detailed explanations would be appreciated.

Link to a model which uses the exact same base, which has the same issue.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WxMQ5QVBu9KuyW_91GDQD-cm7nrxJHSd/view?usp=share_link

[image: After]

Comment: Hint: if you asked a question and nobody even wrote a comment in 6 hours: the reason because of this is in 99% the way you wrote the question. It is absolutely no problem, that you are a beginner, but we cannot help you if you don't know the details. e.g. we have no idea whether you applied scale/rotation etc. So i think it is a good idea if you provide your blend file

Comment: @Chris I can do that. I'll edit the question to add a link to the issue with the model. Though it's a different model which uses the exact same base as I sent the one shown to a friend to be fixed. But I'm hoping providing a link will allow for an answer so I can fix it myself.

Comment: This kind of depends on what you were doing before, but you might try ctrl+p -> Object (Keep Transform) Parent

Comment: @AllenSimpson It seems that fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your finger objects were probably parented to another object before you parented them to the armature, so they simply went back to their location before the first parenting, so first thing unparent with Alt P > Clear And Keep Transformation, then parent to the armature